# Php row set variable detect

Tags: php

How do i set if row detect any text inside url show will echo abc if else show blank like code below

```
<?php
if($row['url']==$url){
echo "abc";
}else{
 print "none";
}
?>
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Are you looking for [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos)?

Comment: i have 1 column "url" in mysql so i want to set if everytime user insert form and didnt put anything inside url column set to none else set to abc for in php example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want like this:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if (strpos($url,'<find_text_name>') !== false) {
    echo 'find_text_name exists.';
} else {
    echo 'No find_text_name.';
}
```